# How to disabled the https from x-cart?

Tags: php, https, x-cart

I accidentally enabled https in X-Cart from localhost, there after can not login in admin panel and therefor can not disable the same, please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How have you enabled https in x-cart? Can you post here your `.htaccess` content?

Comment: From admin panel System Settings =>Https Settings=>enable https

Comment: Try to open .htaccess file in text editor (on root), than copy its content in your question. (I do not see that option in admin, what version do you use?)

Comment: I am using x cart 5, I am not able to past the .htaccess content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you need the following:

1)Reset the values of the fields **admin_security** and **customer_security** in your store's database. These fields can be found in the table **xc_config**, provided that during X-Cart installation you chose to use the MySQL table prefix "xc_".

The following MySQL statement will select the fields in question from the database table xc_config:

SELECT * FROM `xc_config` WHERE `name` LIKE "%security%";
The following statement will reset the field values:
UPDATE `xc_config` SET `value`=0 WHERE `name`="admin_security" OR `name`="customer_security";

2)Remove the folder var/datacache/ in your X-Cart insallation directory.

The full instruction is available in X-Cart 5 knowledge base:
http://kb.x-cart.com/display/XDD/Inaccessible+Admin+area+after+enabling+HTTPS